# Save text file with PHP using Javascript code

Tags: php, javascript

This is the code of a simply button.

```
<input value="Download" type="button" onclick=" inccount();" />
```

And here this is what `inccount();` does:

```
function inccount() {
 var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("num").value);
 document.getElementById("num").value = a + 1;
}
```

As you can see, this function increments by 1 the number I have on the input field `num`. I'd like to save this number on my server, but if I call a php script with the `<form>` tag, the page changes.

I want save the content of `count` on my server without leaving the current page. Who could I do it?

I wrote this simply PHP script for save the content of the input field (that is called `num`):

```
<?php
$file = '/dat/count.txt';
$current = $_GET["num"];
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Comment: If you need not refresh the page and submit a value to the backend script, you can use ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

To update a page without leaving it you need to investigate [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/AJAX). From the linked page:

> in the AJAX model, web applications are able to make quick,
>   incremental updates to the user interface without reloading the entire
>   browser page.

The Ajax call can be to a PHP script that writes to a text file.

Answer (score 0):

You are Posting the Page to the Server. So, the Page will have changes..

You need to use `AJAX` request from javascript to the Server.

simply with JQuery

```
$.ajax(
{
    url:'/?num=' + $('#num').val(),
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(response){
        alert('Success');
    },
    error: function(e1,e2,e3){
        alert('Error occured, Could not able to make request.');
    }

});
```